# Get the position of an object on a Matlab plot

Tags: user-interface, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How is it possible to get, directly from the Matlab command window, the position (i.e. the coordinates) of an object (e.g. an arrow, a rectangle or sim.) that I have drawn on a plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually do this using the handle graphics properties.  For example:

Make a plot

```
h = plot(1:10, rand(10,1));
```

Then get the actual values of the points
    x = get(h,'xdata')
    y = get(h,'ydata')

Different types of objects have different properties, sometimes you have to explore.  In that case this syntax is useful.

```
get(h)  %This displays all available properties on `h` to the command window
```

A final useful tidbit is the `gco` ("get current object") function, which provides the handle of the last item that you plotted or manually clicked on.  This can help if you're not sure where the plotted item came from.

---

Edit:

To find all of the properties which are descendents of an object, use either `findobj`, or `findall`.  For example:

```
findobj(gcf);  %Returns all non-hidden, typical objects.  This should be your first attempt.
findall(gcf);  %Returns all children, even hidden object, such as titles, manually added annotations, and UI menus
```

This call removes some common UI annotations

```
get(findall(gcf,'-not','type','uimenu','-not','type','uitoggletool','-not','type','uipushtool','-not','type','uitogglesplittool'),'type')
```

(Presumably  the last example could be improved with a properly designed regexp, but I can't seem to get that working right now.)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was quite useful.
Using the command "gco", "get" and "set" I can control the properties of the last object I put on the plot. 
There just one more thing I need: how can I list ALL the objects that are on the plot?

Comment: `findobj(gcf)` provides the handles of all descendants of the current figure.  `findobj` is very useful for this kind of work, it also can filter the list based on property values (or logical combinations thereof).  `help findobj` for more.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work :(
Here is my example. I created a simple plot 

    t = 0:.25:3*pi;
    y=0.9*sin(t).*(t);
    plot(t, y);


and then I added just a line and a rectangle. 
If I select one of them, with the command "gco" I get the corresponding handle and so I have access to all its properties. 
On the other hand, using findobj(gcf) I get three handles but there is no correspondence with the previous ones.

Comment: See edit.  The answer is `findall`.  (Which I just learned about.)

Comment: You are right! The solution is `findall` and the expression to filter all the different handles is quite simple...
 `findall(gcf, 'type', 'hggroup')` 
This command just gives you all the handles of the objects you put on the plot, so lines, arrows, retangles and etc.

Now I need to know how I have to modify this command when my plot is part of a GUI.

Thanks a lot for your help!